# Why does signing in with Mechanize on website redirect to the home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to connect automaticaly to a website using Mechanize.

I read searched the internet but I can't find any solution to my problem, which is why, after running `form.submit`, I get returned to the home page?

Is it possible to get a log when I try to connect?

My code:

```
 mechanize = Mechanize.new do |agent| 
    agent.user_agent_alias = "Linux Mozilla"
 end 

page = mechanize.get("http://website.org/")
 form = mechanize.page.forms.first
  puts form.content
 form.username = "mylogin"
 form.password = "mypassword"
form.submit
```

The snippet code of the website:

```
<div id="signincontainer">
    <form method="POST" action="http://website.org/" name="FL" id="signin">
      <input name="op" value="login" type="hidden">
      <input name="redirect" value="" type="hidden">
      <span class="signinq">
      <input style="background: url('images/username.png') no-repeat scroll 5px 50% rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="username" name="login" title="username" tabindex="4" type="text">
      <a class="donthaveaccount" href="http://website.org/signup.html"><span>
      Sign Up
      </span></a> </span> <span class="signinq">
      <input style="background: url('images/password.png') no-repeat scroll 5px 50% rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="password" name="password" value="" title="password" tabindex="5" type="password">
      <a class="forgotpassword" href="http://website.org/forgot-pass.html" id="resend_password_link"><span>
      Forgot your password?
      </span></a> </span>
      <input id="signin_submit" value="Enviar" tabindex="6" src="images2/signin.png" type="image">
    </form>
  </div>
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3-p484 and Mechanize 2.0.1.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why you're being redirected. You're trying to set a `user_agent_alias`, but that signature isn't very realistic if you're trying to [mimic Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference).

Comment: i trying without user_agent_alias and i get the same error. i cant connect

Comment: What happens if you use one that is an exact copy of what Mozilla sends for a Windows or Linux browser? There's no guarantee that the problem is there, but some sites refuse connections if the string doesn't match well enough. They shouldn't but they do.

Comment: if i try with ..alias = "Mac Safari" or "Linux Firefox" i get the same error

Comment: but if i use login_field = login_form.field_with(name: "login").value = "zyriuse"
   password_field = login_form.field_with(name: "password").value = "" without password i get invalid login or password and if write a password i get nothing ??

Comment: Neither "Mac Safari" or "Linux Firefox" are full agent strings. See the Mozilla site for their agent strings for a full ID. It's very possible that after the authentication form they're redirecting you to another page, and that action sniffs the agent string. There's no way to know unless you ask them what their requirements are. We can't help you much because you won't say what site you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the Tin Man** i find the full ID for Mozilla but i get the same problem, when i write nothing in password i get wrong password or login, but when i write my password i get nothing ?

i've improve my code.

agent = Mechanize.new{ |a| a.log = Logger.new("Mechanize.log") }
agent.read_timeout = 60

```
def add_cookie(agent, uri, cookie)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  Mechanize::Cookie.parse(uri, cookie) do |cookie|
    agent.cookie_jar.add(uri, cookie)
  end
end

agent.user_agent_alias =  'Linux Mozilla'
        {
          'Linux Mozilla' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624',
          'Linux Firefox' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.1) Gecko/20100122 firefox/3.6.1'
         }

   agent.get("http://youwatch.org/?op=my_files")
           form = agent.page.parser.css('form')[0]
            agent.page.forms[0]["login"] = "zyriuse"
            agent.page.forms[0]["password"] = "pbxk@1064"
        f = agent.page.forms[0].submit
   puts f.content
```

Comment: the code above working .i dont know why i get a wrong cookie each time i run this script